# How to pass object as an argument to a function which requires three arguments?

Tags: javascript

I have a function, eg.:

```
function calculateSize(first, second, third) { ... }
```

and I want to pass to it an object which looks like this:

```
const values = {
  first: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100
  },
  second: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100
  },
  third: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100
  }
};
```

How can I do it in a most succinct way?

Comment: The safest way is to do `const { first, second, third } = values` and then call `calculateSize(first, second, third)`.

Comment: If you're hoping for a "smart" solution, there is none.

Answer (score -1):

Spread the object values into the function call.

```
calculateSize(...Object.values(values));
```

Comment: It's important to note this only works if you don't care about the order of the arguments

Comment: Sure it does - `Object.values` does have a guaranteed order, given an object, in all but a few pathological cases. Since OP's object's values are defined in the desired order, it'll work.

Comment: Well, we know the object "looks like* that, but there's no guarantee that one property or another hasn't been added or removed at some point. I tend to regard reliance on property ordering to make some architectural detail work to be a pretty risky idea.

Answer (score -2):

You could write like this:

```
function calculateSize({first, second, third}) { ... }
```